# A curious generalization of Helly's theorem

Tags: discrete-geometry, co.combinatorics

Here is a curious conjectural extension of Helly's theorem.

It may follow (if true) from a useful theorem of the kind asked in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78585/a-desirable-extension-of-the-nerve-theorem):

> **Conjecture:** Let ${\cal F}=P_1,P_2,\dots,P_m$ be a family all
>   whose members are disjoint union of
>   two convex sets in $R^d$. Suppose also
>   that
>
> (1) $m \ge d+2$
>
> (2) Every intersection of $i$
>   members of $\cal F$, $i < m$ is also
>   the disjoint union of two NONEMPTY *compact* convex sets.
>
> Then the intersections of all members
>   of $\cal F$ is not empty.

Remark: Micha A. Perles showed (in the 70s) that even when $d=2$ you cannot replace "two" by "48".

Comment: A friend of mine did her master thesis on Helly type theorems: http://www2.math.su.se/gemensamt/grund/exjobb/matte/2008/rep2/report.pdf
You might find something there.

Comment: So if I see well, this question is a special case of the characterization of the f-vectors of d-representable colored simplicial complexes which has been open for a long time (but probably the known results are enough to give a proof for d=2). Could you recommend a survey of these results?

Comment: Hi Domotorp, i dont see the precise connection.

Comment: E.g. if d=2, then you basically have 8 sets, colored with four colors, two in each class, but we don't even have to care about the colors. Take the f-vector of their nerve complex, i.e. where f_i denotes how many i+1 of them intersect. Then your condition demands that f_3 is 0, f_2 is 8 (four triples with two intersections each) and f_1 is 12 (six pairs with two intersections each), plus you demand a little more because of the colors. I think you know Eckhoff's conditions better than me...

Comment: Dear Domotorp, you are right. Indeed these questions can be regarded as questions about multicolored representable complexes although they are not directly related to questions about f-vectors. Interesting! 

Answer (score 4):

**This answer provides a nice background to the question.**

I can say that a theorem similar to the one in the OP is certainly true. The following was conjectured by Grünbaum and Motzkin in [1] and later proved by Amenta in [2].

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathcal C$ be a family of sets in $\mathbb R^d$ such that the intersection of any non-empty finite subfamily of $\mathcal C$ is the disjoint union of at most $k$ closed convex sets. Then the intersection of all sets in $\mathcal C$ is non-empty if and only if the intersection of any $k(d+1)$ elements of $\mathcal C$ is non-empty.

In particular this implies that the conjecture in the OP is true when $m\geq 2d+3$. I believe there are counter examples for $m\le k(d+1)$, showing it is best possible.

**References**

[1] Branko Grünbaum, Theodore S. Motzkin, "[On components in some families of sets](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034254)" Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 12, No. 4, 607-613, doi:10.2307/2034254, [MR0159262](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0159262), [Zbl 0106.01001](https://zbmath.org/0106.01001).

[2] Nina Amenta, "[Helly-type theorems and Generalized Linear Programming](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02574379)" "Discrete & Computational Geometry 12, 241–261 (1994), [EuDML: 131330](https://eudml.org/doc/131330), [MR1298910](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1298910), [Zbl 0819.90056](https://zbmath.org/0819.90056).

Comment: Yes. the point is what happens when you replace "at most k" with "exactly k" for k=2 (and maybe also k=3)

Answer (score 3):

**This answer refers to an earlier, slightly inaccurate, version of the problem. (GK)**

I think your conditions might be insufficient, even if in (2) you require the intersection to be a convex set. If d=1, first take three intervals, A, B and C. Your sets can be $A\cup B$, $B\cup C$ and $A\cup C$. The intersection of any two will be an interval.

A similar example if d=2 is to take four squares, $A=[0,1]\times [0,1]$, $B=[0,1]\times [1,3]$, $C=[1,3]\times [0,1]$, $D=[1,3]\times [1,3]$. Now take the four sets to be $conv(A,B)\cup C$, $conv(B,C)\cup D$, $conv(C,D)\cup A$, $conv(D,A)\cup B$. The intersection of any three sets will be a square.

Comment: Dear Domotorp, I forgot to say that the intersection should be the disjoin union of two non empty convex sets.

Comment: Well, convex sets are usually easy to split into two, non-empty convex sets... Maybe you want that their closures do not intersect or their distance is non-zero or something like that.

Comment: compact, the point here and in the previous question that all non empty intersection are of the same homotopic type.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer shows that you cannot strengthen the conditions of the questions and demand condition (2) only for $m-1$ sets.**

Answer for new version IF we only consider the intersection of m-1 sets (as construction fails otherwise, as pointed out by Gil in the comment):
Now it is not hard to prove that the statement is true for d=1 but there is a counterexample for d=2. Take a circle and divide its perimeter into six equal parts, A, B, .., F such that e.g. A, B and C are on the top. Now take a point somewhere high, P, and another somewhere low, Q. Our four sets will be the following: conv(A,P) $\cup$ conv(D,Q), conv(B,P) $\cup$ conv(E,Q), conv(C,P) $\cup$ conv(F,Q) and finally the last set is the disc. Now the intersection of the first three will be around P and Q, while the intersection of the fourth with any two other sets will be around two disjoint arcs of the perimeter.

Comment: Dear Domotorp, I was first worried about the intersection of the first third and the disk. But this looks ok. Now I am a bit worried about the intersection of the first and third. Doesnt it contain something around P something around Q and also something around the intersection of A and F and something around the intersection of C and D?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have only considered intersections of three sets.