# Two-point condition (p,q)-theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Suppose that for a finite collection of planar convex sets $\mathcal F$ the following holds.
Any hundred members of $\mathcal F$ can be stabbed by two points, i.e., there are two points such that each of the hundred sets contains (at least) one of the points.
Does it follow that all members of $\mathcal F$ can be stabbed by three points?

Replacing two with one gives the famous $(p,q)$-theorem. But surprisingly, the above doesn't hold if we replace three with two; see M. Katchalski and D. Nashtir: On a conjecture of Danzer and Grünbaum (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 124 (1996), 3213-3218, doi: 10.1090/S0002-9939-96-03806-3), pointed out in the answer by Gjergji Zaimi to this [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382164/two-point-helly) of mine.

What about the more general problem in $\mathbb R^d$, replacing hundred/two/three by appropriate values?